# How to use shortcuts with the AZERTY keyboard input within PyCharm?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community 4.5.3 with Gnome / Fedora 21.

I can easily switch from en (US English) to fr (French) keyboard layout by using a dropdown switch menu on the top right corner of the screen, such as:

[image: switch keyboard layout]

While PyCharm code editor does indeed understand the switch (I can use AZERTY or QWERTY at will), **it is not the case for shortcuts such as Ctr+A for "select all"**. For some reasons, PyCharm always thinks that I am using the first language which appears in the drop-down menu, i.e. QWERTY for English (US).

Is there another command somewhere that I could use to make PyCharm understand the keyboard input switch for shortcuts?

Comment: I think you need to [setup an alternate keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the most important ones for now: select all, undo, redo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can [setup an alternate keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) to switch when you change languages.